# Sly, Cunning, Clever or Shrewd?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, word-difference

I'm looking for the best word that means "*being able to reach goals indirectly, perhaps, but not necessarily, with cheating or deception*".
(basically I'm trying to find the best translation for the russian word "хитрый")

I think that without context that word should have a neutral meaning. But depending on a context it can appear as a good or a bad quality.

For example:

"Being a [xxx] person he was able to calm his boss down and stop the approaching conflict in the team" - an example when it serves as a good quality.

"Being a [xxx] person she was able to make her fiancé forgive her and even buy her that diamond necklace she wanted, although he had to spend all his savings on it" - an example when it serves as a bad quality.

"The [xxx] fox flattered the crow,  and got crow's cheese" (a summary of the Ivan Krylov's fable "The Fox and the Crow") - another example where it serves as not a good (at least for the crow :) quality

Comment: For me, *shrewd* is okay in all sentences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with cunning for the second sentence, but *sly* is used more to describe foxes (albeit 'sly' and 'cunning' being synonyms in dictionary.com). Hence the very common phrase 'sly fox', although 'cunning fox' yields some results.

I disagree with using cunning/sly at all for the first sentence, as they both have negative connotations the majority of the time. 'Clever' would probably suit the best.

Answer (score 1):

**Cunning** is probably your best choice as it has connotations of deception, whereas *clever* and *sly* may or may not use deception (I'm assuming *omission* (sly in some cases) is differentiated from *deception*, (though some may think it is a form of deception).